# Exchanging variables between PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

The selected radio button will show its corresponding list of cities by a dropdown box.
For example, upon the selected radio button ‘Ontario’, a dropdown box with matching cities will show up (in this example the ‘Region’ is Ontario and the id is 77).

All PHP functions, loops and the JavaScript code mentioned below in the example, are working correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#locationTree input:radio').change(function() {
    var buttonPressed = $('input:radio[name=Region]:checked').val();

    if(buttonPressed == 77) {
      var listCities = $("select[name='City']");
      <?php View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView(77); ?>
      <?php while(has_list_cities()) { ?>
        $("<option><?php echo list_city_name(); ?></option>").appendTo(listCities);
      <?php } ?>                
    } 

  });   
});
</script>
```

To get list of cities by different regions and not specifically to 77, I can slightly change the PHP code as follows:

```
 <?php View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView($regionCode); ?>
```

and since the variable ‘buttonPressed’ detects the selected id of ‘Region’, I can add the following simple script:

```
<?php $regionCode = "<script>document.write(buttonPressed)</script>"; ?>
```

After the above changes:

```
var listCities = $("select[name='City']");
<?php $regionCode = "<script>document.write(buttonPressed)</script>"; ?>   
<?php View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView($regionCode); ?>
```

I know PHP is run server side and JavaScript is run client side but I thought that my simple solution for exchanging variables between PHP and JavaScript should work… but it doesn’t work. I really ask someone help me get it working.

Comment: Looks to me like you're expecting the `$regionCode` variable to be set by running some javascript, and as you say, PHP runs on the server, so by the time that javascript code runs, the page has long since left the server, and it does'nt work like that. You'll have to use ajax to get a `newInstance()` based on a button clicked on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange variables (sever to client) by using the data attribute properties HTML 5 provides.  I do this for initial page loads.

To exchange variables after the initial page load, one may use ajax calls.

**data attribute example**

*HTML via PHP Write*

```
<div id='universals' data-path='/zz/' data-load='1'></div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
var data_dom = $('#universals')[0],
    key,
    universals = [];
for (key in data_dom.dataset) {
    universals[key] = data_dom.dataset[key];
}
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback, can you advise why my simple solution is not working?

Comment: Refactor your code so that you are not using php to write your javascript.  It's not wrong but it's hard to read.  If you need server side variables send them via ajax or use data attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to understand it and hopefully I can implement it.

Comment: Once you separate you code a bit, I think it will make more sense.  What don't you understand in my example?

Comment: I know PHP, some JavaScript but my Ajax knowledge is very basic. What do you mean by separating my code? I have a JavaScript variable which I know its value (buttonPressed), where to use it in your code? and then how to pass this value to PHP ($regionCode)?

Comment: `Refactor your code so that you are not using php to write your javascript` - again, does this make sense?