# PHP value inside JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The following code works fine, the function `load()` sends the selected radio button info to the PHP page and display the returned:

```
<head>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButtons input:radio').change(function() {
      var buttonValue = $("#myButtons input:radio:checked").val();
        $("#myDiv").load('myPHPfile.php', {selectedButtonValue : buttonValue});
    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myButtons">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="10" />ButtonA 
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="20" />ButtonB
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="30" />ButtonC
  </div>
  <div id="myDiv">Click the button to load results</div>
</body>
```

myPHPfile.php

```
<?php 
  if( $_REQUEST["selectedButtonValue"] )
  {
     $buttonPHP = $_REQUEST['selectedButtonValue'];
     echo "Value button is ". $buttonPHP;
  }
?>
```

I need an alert box message of the returned PHP value, inside the script, as follows:

```
;

  $("#myDiv").load('myPHPfile.php', {selectedButtonValue : buttonValue});
  alert(<?php $buttonPHP ?>);

;
```

Would it be possible to write the PHP value inside JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a callback function in `.load()`, like this:

```
$("#myDiv").load('myPHPfile.php', 
    {selectedButtonValue : buttonValue}, 
    function(data){
        alert(data);
});
```

If you only want the value of the `$buttonPHP` to be displayed in the alert, change your `echo` to

```
echo $buttonPHP;
```

instead of

```
echo "Value button is ". $buttonPHP;
```

**Note: There is an issue with `.load()` function. It will not work if you access your html page locally/directly, you need to put it on a server. Or you can use xampp, wampserver, etc. **

*Hope it helps.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply, tested and working fine (an alert box message appears), but I need $buttonPHP as mentioned before, alert('<?php echo $buttonPHP; ?>'). The reason for that is because I need to use this value for another code in the same JavaScript.

Comment: In my sample, the alerted value is the value of `$buttonPHP`. If you want to use the value outside the callback function, just assign it to a `var` like: `var buttnPHP = data;`

Comment: But then again, it will not be a PHP value. I must get it as PHP value since inside my JavaScript there is a PHP loop which is using this value. Please could you help me on this matter.

Comment: Can you post the php loop inside your script?

Comment: <?php View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView(77); ?>
      <?php while(has_list_cities()) { ?>

Comment: just need to replace the number 77 with $ buttonPHP

Comment: Uh.... I can't seem to visualize what you want to do. Can you update your post(question) and put the whole script which contains that loop?

Comment: Please see the link below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185331/exchanging-variables-between-php-and-javascript

Comment: Try using `$_SESSION` in php so that you can use `$buttonPHP` in another page. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page) might help.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, I’ve tried the $_SESSION solution, but it didn’t do anything.

Comment: @user203952: Did you put a `session_start();` in your `myPHPfile.php` and in your `html`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, almost had it:

```
alert('<?php echo $buttonPHP; ?>');
```

Comment: This will not really work because by the time the script is loaded it gets the value of the php variable.

Comment: @user203952: I have posted an answer, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your doing it right now, but you need to output the value:

```
alert(<?php echo $buttonPHP ?>);
```

On a sidenote, it seems like you don't have it really clear to you what happens.
HTML, css and javascript runs on the clients(the visitors) computer and the PHP code runs on the server, that means that the you can always combine php output with client-side code, and this is done regularly, just as you have done.

This is also one of the reasons why PHP is so flamed as a language, because of it low threshold to get started with, it is way to easy to create code that works, but that is a hell to maintain.

This is not a comment to your code, but a general reflection on php.

Comment: Thanks’, I’ve tried both your answer and the other, but none is working. Without the alert code, the script works fine.

Comment: Where exactly does the javascript code with the alertbutton reside? In the php-file that gets called via ajax or on the html page, or somewhere else?

Comment: JavaScript code with the alert button resides on the html page

Comment: any other suggestion, Thx.?

Answer (score 0):

Either, you have to put the alert in the PHP generated code:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Value button is ". $buttonPHP . "');</script>";
```

Or you have to use `$.get` function:

```
$.get('myPHPfile.php', {selectedButtonValue : buttonValue}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the ‘$get()’ direction, the syntax is not working, hopefully I will try to indent your code.