# Restart countdown timer when time is 10AM, countdown timer are base from the data in the database

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I hope you can help me. I have the followong PHP code where I'm going to extract the countdown time from the database.

```
require "inc/config.php";    
$sql = "SELECT countdown_start FROM counter";
    
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        
if($result->num_rows > 0):
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<span class="timer" value="<?php echo $row["countdown_start"]; ?>"></span>
<?php }
endif;
```

The countdown starts base from the output and look like this:

```
<span class="timer" value="12:10:00"></span>
<span class="timer" value="15:35:00"></span>
<span class="timer" value="10:05:00"></span>
<span class="timer" value="18:45:00"></span>
```

This is the script i am using which i found from the internet but I can't make it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){        
      $('.timer').each(function(){
         $(this).countdown($(this).attr('value'), function(event) {
         $(this).text(
        event.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
       );
      });
    });
 });
</script>
```

It is not working. I get a console error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function"

Also I want to automatically restart the countdown when it's 10am in my local time. Meaning if the countdown reaches zero, it will stop, then all timer automatically restarts at 10am.

I followed this -> https://jsfiddle.net/smh5nhgz/1/

Comment: HI. There is little to no connection between the time values selected in the PHP server code and the jquery front-end code that runs a countdown timer that shows the duration left to the start of the next year. It is not really clear what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated my question. Please take a look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exchanging variables between PHP and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185331/exchanging-variables-between-php-and-javascript)

Comment: No that's so different.  When all countdown timer reaches zero, they all stop. Then at exactly 10am my local time, the countdown restarts again. My first issue is how to make the countdown work. The next is how to make all countdown timer restarts at 10am.

Comment: Can anyone guide me how to implement this? thanks